# libsoup-2.4 is being craved

Tags: compiling, libraries, configure

I tried to install a program from source on my Debian-based machine so I ran `./waf configure` and this was my output:

`Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : /usr/bin/pkg-config 
Checking for 'gobject-2.0'               : yes 
Checking for 'gthread-2.0'               : yes 
Checking for program 'valac-0.8'         : not found 
Checking for program 'valac'             : /usr/bin/valac 
Checking for valac version >= (0, 8, 0)  : (0, 34, 7) 
Checking for program 'msgfmt'            : /usr/bin/msgfmt 
Checking for program 'perl'              : /usr/bin/perl 
Checking for program 'intltool-merge'    : /usr/bin/intltool-merge 
Checking for header locale.h             : yes 
Checking for program 'glib-genmarshal'   : /usr/bin/glib-genmarshal 
Checking for program 'glib-mkenums'      : /usr/bin/glib-mkenums 
Checking for program 'glib-compile-schemas' : /usr/bin/glib-compile-schemas 
Checking for program 'glib-compile-resources' : /usr/bin/glib-compile-resources 
Checking for program 'valac-0.28'             : /usr/bin/valac 
Checking for valac-0.28 version >= (0, 28, 0) : (0, 34, 7) 
Checking for 'glib-2.0'                       : yes 
Checking for 'gio-2.0'                        : yes 
Checking for 'gobject-2.0'                    : yes 
Checking for 'gmodule-2.0'                    : yes 
Checking for 'gtk+-3.0'                       : yes 
Checking for 'libsoup-2.4'                    : not found`

The problem is: I already have **libsoup-2.4-1** installed. And the required dependencies, as stated by the program's author, are:

...
`libsoup        >=2.4`
...

But replacing the new version with the old one would cause some general problems on the system I suppose, so I didn't want to try to do that, nor do I find that smart to do since the new version should work as good as the old one.

What can I do to make this program compilable?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `libsoup` development package, `libsoup2.4-dev`:

```
sudo apt install libsoup2.4-dev
```

You need to install `libsoup2.4-dev` and `libsoup2.4-1` (which the `-dev` package depends on) as a matched pair, with the same version. So if you already have `libsoup2.4-1` installed, you need to install the matching `libsoup2.4-dev` — whether by downgrading `libsoup2.4-1` if necessary, or by installing `libsoup2.4-dev` from the same repository as your installed version of `libsoup2.4-1`.

Comment: This package requires libsoup2.48.0-1, but when I try to install this one it says *a later version is already installed*.

Comment: What version of `libsoup2.4-1` do you have? If you’re running Debian 8 you should have 2.48.0-1.

Comment: If you have another version of `libsoup2.4-1`, you need to either downgrade that to 2.48.0-1, or install the matching `libsoup2.4-dev` (from wherever you got `libsoup2.4-1`).

Comment: Mos of the dependencies I had to look up on packages.debian.org

Answer (score 0):

To add to Stephen's answer, `configure` uses `pkgconfig` to check for installed libraries, which in turn reads the configuration from `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libsoup-x.y.pc` file. Since you only need this file for development, it is included in `-dev` package.

Regarding the troubles you have with package versions, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524377/how-to-setup-libsoup-for-ubuntu) question may be useful.